# How to aggregate rows on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to group different years in my dataset so that I can see the total number of login_log_id each year has(BigQuery)

```sql
SELECT login_log_id,
DATE(login_time) as login_date,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM login_time) as login_year,
TIME(login_time) as login_time,
FROM `steel-time-347714.flex.logs`
GROUP BY login_log_id
```

I want to make a group by so that I can see total number of login_log_id generated in different years.

My columns are `login_log_id`, `login_time`

I am getting following error :-

> SELECT list expression references column login_time which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:6]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to be more clear about you problem, add an example of your table and the expected output and what you already tried to solve. Take a look in the How to Ask page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I edited it all for better clarity

Answer (score 2):

The error is because every column you refer to in the select need to be aggregated or be in the `GROUP BY`.

If you want the total logins by year, you can do:

```sql
SELECT 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM login_time) as login_year,
  COUNT(1) as total_logins,
  COUNT(DISTINCT login_log_id) as total_unique_logins
FROM `steel-time-347714.flex.logs`
GROUP BY login_year
```

But if you want the total by login_log_id and year:

```sql
SELECT 
  login_log_id,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM login_time) as login_year,
  COUNT(1) as total_logins
FROM `steel-time-347714.flex.logs`
GROUP BY login_log_id, login_year
```

Comment: Thank you so much I wanted the first solution you provided.